# Firebase returns response object but does not send verification code to my SIM card using react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

So I am gonna cut to the chase... I have tried to integrate RNFB to my project but it ended up breaking it. Thus I cloned their repo for their template and I copied my old project and all is working fine. Now here is the new struggle I am facing...

I am using phone verification on iOS and I got it working to the point where my app is receiving a response from firebase as follows:

```
Confirmation: { _auth: authObject, _confirmationId: 
'dafdfasjdhfbslakhbflsadfbsldjfhbsdaljfhbsladkjfhbsadjlbfjlhdfbalsjhb'}
```

Now I dont know if this is the correct response to use then and confirm the code that I should receive or not I didn't try to confirm it yet because I am not receiving the confirmation SMS...

Yep, this is where I am stuck now.  I tried 3 sim cards in 3 different countries with the correct format but I am not receiving any SMS with any code...

I made sure that my testing list is empty in firebase and I am using the correct phone number format.

Do you guys have any idea? I am using RNFB 5 and latest RN version.

Comment: have you checked your test list of phone auth ?

Comment: @Ashish yes its currently empty and i made sure to use correct phone number format.

Comment: @Ashish does the object format i am getting back in my response looks normal to you? because i cannot see codeVerification Id? the id I am getting back under _confirmationId is a very long string of numbers and characters.